# How can I sync my jetpack joyride profile between my surface and windows 8 laptop?

Tags: windows, jetpack-joyride, windows-8

All of my coins, vehicle upgrades and achievements have synced but my profile says that I am level 1 even though I am level 53 on my laptop.

I am using the same Microsoft account for both devices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: I do not have Windows 8.1 so I cannot entirely verify this. [Source.](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-change-metro-apps-default-installation-location-in-windows-8/)

Windows stores apps like Jetpack Joyride in a folder located in your Program Files. It's a hidden folder so go to View -> Hidden Items. The folder is called "WindowsApps".

In order to access this folder you'll have to take ownership of it. [Follow these instructions to do that.](http://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-take-ownership-permission-of-a-file-or-folder-manually-in-windows/) Then once you enter that folder, you should be able to find Jetpack Joyride in it's folder. It'll probably be something like com.halfbirck.etc... or halfbrick.etc... Unfortunately, I can't do more for you there, as I don't have the game. Hopefully this helped!

Comment: I don't know why I gave you this bounty because it does not really help at all with the question